# Regular expressions with square brackets in gnome search

Tags: gnome

I use gnome-search-tool for searching files/folders. There I can put regular expression to filter through file names. I need some help with my custom filter (search).

My folders have format: `myFolder[year][language]`.

How can I search for folders which name contains:

- `[year1]` and `[language1]`
- `[language1]` or `[language2]`
- from `[year1]` to `[year2]`

[image: gnome-search-tool and regexpr]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using a backslash to escape the brackets?  \\[2012\\]

Comment: Yes, I did. Does not work.

Comment: What exactly have you tried that does not work? Escaping the brackets is surely one thing you will have to do, but if you say "does not work" it means that you are doing something else wrong.